# Record Deleted - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I can't open an ACCDB file I have - I just receive a message saying:

> Record Deleted

I've tried compacting it from the command prompt to no avail.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Seems your db is corrupted. Restore a backup. Or try to import the contents into an empty db.

Answer (score 0):

This database almost certainly has a startup module defined that is executing some code.  You can bypass this and open directly to the database window by holding the SHIFT key down while opening your database.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/bypass-startup-options-when-you-open-a-database-ba66917a-68b6-4fe6-8c23-33042953a5f9

Comment: Nope, still same issue im afraid

Comment: Did you do a 'compact and repair' on it?